# C++ - check if safe functions are needed

Tags: c, visual-c++

When I am using Visual Studio (MSVC), and using the `strcat` function, I get the error

> error C4996: 'strcat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

If I was to make a project which was for compilers like `GCC` aswell, is there a way of detecting if these `safe` functions are needed, for example MSVC macro?

Comment: They're never *needed*. As the message says, you can use `strcat`, by defining `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. Do you instead want to know when functions such as `strcat_s` are *available*?

Comment: I don't know if you can do that specifically, but you should be able to do #define _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES 1 to enable the overload. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh%28VS.80%29.aspx . This should help you write code that is portable to GCC as well

Comment: @Dirk `strcat` is a standard library function in both C and C++. How do you know this question isn't about C++?

Comment: @hvd The question isn't about C++ but about a function common to both C and C++. So I thought C would be the better tag.

Comment: @Dirk I'm generally wary of editing tags like that, because it wouldn't surprise me if there's a correct and useful answer that only works in C++, not in C.

Comment: @hvd - Defining `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` makes no difference

Comment: @Joseph Where did you define it? If you defined it in your source file, after the standard library headers, it cannot work. If you defined it in your project options, make sure you're not using now-outdated precompiled headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional compilation for cross-platform code. Such as:

```
#ifdef WIN
strcat_s(...
#else
strcat(...
#endif
```

MSVC compiler detects such calls of the functions that were acknowledged as deprecated and generates warning [C4996](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx) on level 3. So, just compile with this level (or more) and look at warnings.

Comment: using `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)` [from link] gets rid of the problem, thank you very much

Comment: `#pragma warning(disable : 4996)` is the worst possible way to solve your problems! It will mask *other* deprecation warnings that have no link to the CRT. `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` (possibly though `/D` on the compilation command line in the project settings) is a much better way to avoid deprecation of CRT functions and maximize portability.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use `#ifdef _CRT_INSECURE_DEPRECATE` for this. It's the macro used by Visual to add these warnings in the first place, so if you're compiling on a version of Visual that gives warnings, it will be defined.